# When packaging a flask app using flask_socketio with pyinstaller, it throws an error: ValueError: Invalid async_mode specified

Tags: flask, pyinstaller, flask-socketio

I have already tried [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/35). 
I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some_secret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

The error is thrown in the last line of the code

Comment: There is a discussion on using pyinstaller with Flask-SocketIO on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/35. Besides that, you need to be specific about the problem that you are having and the error that you get.